# xhtml not valid after inserting php call

Tags: html, xml, validation, magento, xhtml

I insert into Magento template:

```
xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
```

Which is taken directly from the modern default theme that comes with magento version 1.7. However upon trying to validate the page with W3C i get this error:

> Line 325, Column 10: end tag for "html" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified. You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

```
 Line 2, Column 1: start tag was here
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Any idea how to fix this? I haven't modified header.phtml and don't have a custom one in my theme folder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your template include the  tag at the end – the end tag for html that the validator actually complains about?

Comment: yes, without the php call the entire html validates just fine.

Comment: That also rather supports my theory at you're missing the ending HTML tag. The last file of the template with your opening HTML tag needs to read </html> – and nothing but that.

Comment: Yep you were right, thanks very much! Strange how W3C didn't pick up on the missing html tag without the php call.

Comment: Well, if you really inserted the whole line that you pasted in the original question, then your template just did not include an opening html tag yet; it was just implicit. So then, it did not complain, because there was no unmatched tag. The PHP call is just a part of the tag that you newly introduced, right?

Comment: template did already include opening html tag before i inserted php call.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to validate your PHP document instead of the generated HTML. Don't do this. Put the `.php` on a web server, access the server through your browser and validate the resulting source code.

Comment: I'm validating the html output, not the php document.